# What are the factors/conditions that develop blindness in organisms?

Tags: planets, fauna, vision

I plan that the creatures of my world are usually blind, so they possess sensory organs (barbels) in several variants.

The planet where they are found is cloudy and the peat swamps they inhabit are very lush and permanently shrouded in fog. Is the little light that reaches the undergrowth enough for these creatures to evolve blind? Or there are other more important factors that cause this? The waters are also dark because of the slowly degrading plant matter.

Comment: What's sustaining the lush undergrowth? Sight organs aren't very useful in the absence of light, but it doesn't take much light to make them useful, and enough for plant photosynthesis is certainly enough for sight.

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: Are you talking about actually evolving blindness, or are you talking about never evolving sight? If you're talking about evolving blindness, then first the species would have evolved sight, and then they would suddenly not need it anymore, and those unnecessary traits would be unneeded.

Comment: Their ancestors come from a shallow ocean where there is more light, so after acquiring it.

Comment: Hi, Bellota! Instead of asking for other ways that blindness can evolve (an open-ended question), it is more appropriate for this site to ask if your current concept is (sufficiently) "realistic" (or something else). That way, there is an obvious single right answer.

Comment: do you need organism in one environment to be blind or everything on the planet,  the first is trivial the second is all but impossible if you want multicellular life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. There are actually [many species of fish on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_fish) that don't live in well-lit environments and thus evolved without functional eyes, since there's no need for eyes in an environment where there isn't light to distinguish empty water from a potential predator from your next meal.

So, to answer, **yes, lack of sufficient light can make a species evolve blind**. To ensure this, the environment should be *exceptionally* dark, like underground or in very deep parts of the ocean, since it minimizes the gains that eyes give. Or, if the light is just really dark and not pitch-black, you can also argue that these species wouldn't gain much with regards to escaping their predators even given sight, and it just never evolved that way.

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful. These adaptations should work for detritivorous benthic organisms or those that navigate through mud.